# Attach an error message to a protractor click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webdriver, promise, protractor

Is there a way to attach an error message to a protractor click? Something like the line below is what I expect:

```
button.click('Button not clickable');
```

Currently, if an element is not found, I get the vague error 'Failed: Cannot call method click of undefined'. No line number, no file the error is in, just a generic error and a link to the error occurring in the promise files. It makes it very hard to hunt down where the error is actually occurring

I'd expect it to do something similar to the line below, where I can attach an error message to the toBeTruthy section:

```
expect(button.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy('Button not displayed');
```

If this line fails, I would get an error similar to 'Element not found, Button not displayed'. Much clearer as to what is going on.

Is there a way to attach an error message to a click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [*promise error handling function*](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/543):

```
button.click('Button not clickable').then(function() { 
    // passing case
}, 
function(err) { 
    // error handling here
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that was just what I needed! Glad it was this simple :)